# PTIJ: What should someone do if s/he gets a yeast infection during Pesach?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What happens if someone gets a yeast infection during Pesach? Does s/he need to worry that it may somehow enter the digestive tract and make the food there chametz? If it's in the bladder and mixes with urine or in the anus and mixes with feces, both of which contain digested food, is that a concern? May one handle the infected area or is that considered chametz, too.

If one finds the yeast during Yom Tov, itself, is it considered muktzah, and would one have to cover himself with a blanket or a huge pot until Hol Hamo'ed?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: If it’s in the digestive tract, can it really be considered בל יראה?

Comment: Yeast is not Chometz. See [this link](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/is-bakers-yeast-chametz/) for an explanation.

Comment: @arecaps I know that. It's *machmetzet* which is also prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

Not a general solution, but...

If it's a woman who has such an infection, and the expected time for her next period is during Pesach, then the proper course of action is to not eat horseradish for marror. For, as the saying goes,

"Yeast is yeast, and וסת is vest, and never the chrein shall meet."